# TypeError: Cannot destructure property 'currentUser' of 'Object(...)(...)' as it is undefined

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, firebase-authentication

I'm trying to make a logOut function with firebase on React. I have the following code for the logOut function:

```
const [error, setError] = useState('');
    const { currentUser, logout } = useAuth();

    const handleLogout = async () => {
        try {
            await logout();
        } catch (error) {
            setError('Server error');
        }
    }
```

I'm calling that code on a Link because it is in a navBar:

```
<Link className="nav-link" to="/iniciosesion" onClick={handleLogout}>LogOut</Link>
```

I'm importing useAuth like this:

```
import { useAuth } from '../context/AuthContext';
```

And this is what I have in my AuthContext.js:

```
import React, { createContext, useEffect, useState, useContext } from 'react'
import { auth } from '../firebase' 

const AuthContext = createContext();
export const useAuth = () => useContext(AuthContext);
export const AuthProvider = (props) => {

    const [currentUser, setCurrentUser] = useState({});

    useEffect(() => {
        auth.onAuthStateChanged((user) => {
            setCurrentUser(user);
        })
    }, [])

    const logout = () => auth.signOut();
    const value = { logout, currentUser };

    return (
        <AuthContext.Provider value={value}>
            {props.children}
        </AuthContext.Provider>
    )
}
```

I have searched up and I can't find a solution for this problem.

Comment: It's not clear to me why you are expecting useAuth to return an object that has the properties currentUser and logout.  It's not a Firebase Auth object.

Comment: For what I understand (I'm new using React) is that I initialize useAuth as a context that I can use in other components. The logOut function is using a method from firebase and that's the method I'm trying to call from the "handleLogout" function

Comment: In the same tune as Doug, we need to also see the relevant source to `../firebase` to get any clue as to where your issue stems. Does your error happen when clicking the logout link? Is the `logout` function something custom made (because you're not sourcing it from node modules, that's the assumption I'm making)?

Comment: Yes. The error happens when I click the LogOut Link. The logOut function is custom made. I also have signUp and signIn and those things work well. That's why I know the source to ../firebase is working fine. I didn't include the signUp and signIn methods in the question.

Comment: The thing about that firebase import is that the `auth` that comes from it isn't used anywhere except inside the AuthProvider, which isn't in play at all with useAuth.  It's just not wired up correctly at all.